# OleDb multiple connection in a loop

Tags: c#, oledb

I try to do a multiple connection with Oledb, in order to decrement my variable in my SQL request.

Here is my code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int var = 0;
    string conn = " ... ";
    OleDbConnection connexion = new OleDbConnection(conn);
    connexion.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID, DATA_1, DATA_2 from Database WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX (ID) -" + var + " FROM Database);", connexion);
    OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();

            if (!reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (!reader.HasRows)
                {
                    OleDbConnection connexion2 = new OleDbConnection(conn);
                    connexion2.Open();

                    var++;
                    OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(""SELECT ID, DATA_1, DATA_2 from Database WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX (ID) -" + var + " FROM Database);", connexion2);
                    OleDbDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                    reader2.Read();


                    reader = reader2;
                    reader2.Close();
                    connexion2.Close();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                Label5.Text = "Line Empty";
            }


        }




    reader.Close();
    connexion.Close();
```

}

I have an error Line 76 :

> Attempt to call HasRows Invalid When the driver is close.

Ligne 74 :                 if (!reader.HasRows)

Ligne 75 :                 {

**Ligne 76 :                     while (!reader.HasRows)**     ERROR

Ligne 77 :                     {

Ligne 78 :                         OleDbConnection connexion2 = new OleDbConnection(conn);

Comment: You do `reader = reader2;` and then `reader2.Close();` but reader now refernces the same thing as `reader2` so reader is now closed. What are you trying to do your code is not very clear.

Comment: `OleDbCommand cmd2 = new OleDbCommand(""SELECT ID, DATA_1, DATA_2 from Database WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX (ID) -" + var + " FROM Database);", connexion2);` why the 2 double quotes in the beginning as well... step thru your code as well Peter do not close connections inside of your while loop `while (!reader.HasRows)` also reading the error message tells you right away what's wrong `Attempt to call HasRows Invalid When the driver is close.`

Answer (score 0):

```
reader = reader2;
```

Because of that line, `reader` is now closed in the next loop iteration.

Comment: @Peter I doubt you really want to close reader2 as that is the "new" reader you want to use.  You want to close reader before setting reader2 to it.

Comment: Why are you assigning `reader` at all? Do you understand what your code means?

Comment: juharr, I just want to transfer in  reader the content of reader2, in order to re-execute my loop " while (!reader.HasRows) " to check if he hasn't records in my database.

Answer (score 0):

You set `reader` to `reader2` and then close `reader2`, that means the object that `reader` references is closed.  So when the loop starts again `while (!reader.HasRows)` will throw an exception because the `reader` is closed.  You probably want to close `reader` then set `reader2` to `reader`.

```
reader.Close();
reader = reader2;
```

instead of

```
reader = reader2;
reader2.Close();
```

Although to be completely honest the entire while loop doesn't seem to serve any purpose here as you do not use any of the data that you are retrieving from your sql queries.

Answer (score 0):

First off, parameterize, parameterize! Don't leave your queries open to injection. Also, try to understand and practice utilization of the `using` statement to prevent random resources being locked up. Try this code and see how things work for you. Not sure if this is what you're looking to do as your code is very unclear as is your description of what you're attempting to do. Hope this helps, if not, try to firm up your explanation of what you need to accomplish.

```
string conn = " ... ";
using (OleDbConnection connexion = new OleDbConnection(conn))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT ID, DATA_1, DATA_2 from Database WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX (ID) FROM Database WHERE DATA_1 IS NOT NULL AND DATA_2 IS NOT NULL);", connexion))
{
    connexion.Open();
    using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Label5.Text  = reader["DATA_1"].ToString();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Label5.Text = "Line Empty";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use C# with SQL for a ASP.net project. With a SQL request I select the Last ID in my database and in C# with OleDbDataReader I check each record if he hasn't (null) (null) like in my example and I decrement my ID until to have a Data in a column. 

But I can't check my record when he has a jump between 2 records.

Comment: @Peter First off, you need to decrement? In the case of `var++` you are incrementing. So say you started with 9857375, your next iteration would be 9857376, you want it to return the records in 9857371?

Comment: In my SQL resquest I decrement with my variable "var". I start the record in 9857376, and I want to decrement this ID until to find a data. 9857370  Data   (null)
9857371 (null)  (null)
9857375 (null)  (null)  
9857376 (null)  (null)

Comment: @Peter That is "incrementing". Decrementing would go backwards, as in 9857376 9857375, 9857371, 9857370, etc. Why no just change your query to `SELECT ID, DATA_1, DATA_2 from Database WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX (ID) @Value FROM Database WHERE DATA_1 IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: Volearix, in my sql request I do  SELECT MAX (RSIM_ID) - " + var + " so I decrement with the minus before my variable "var".

Comment: Or you could do `SELECT ID, DATA_1, DATA_2 from Database WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX (ID) @Value FROM Database WHERE DATA_1 IS NOT NULL AND DATA_2 IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: I can't do your SQL request because sometimes I have no records between "real" records, example: between my id 9857375 and 9857371. So I need to decrement to find a record with a DATA like in my record 9857370.

Comment: @Peter What happens with the above altered code? Do you return the max result with non null values in your label5 control? I posted new code.

Comment: Yes my SQL request with var = 0 so my SQL request is : SELECT ID, DATA_1, DATA_2 from Database WHERE ID = ( SELECT MAX (ID) -0 FROM Database);    it return the last record of my database.

Comment: Right, so if within your SQL statement you add a check for `NULL` values you should return the highest values without `NULL` data.

Comment: When he hasn't records I can't check values because my record are not considerate as NULL, but this line " if (!reader.HasRows) " work to know if he hasn't records after my SQL request with oleDBcommand.